# Webcam listed in lsusb but not in /dev/video0

Tags: linux, drivers, virtual-machine, logitech-webcam

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-93-generic x86_64), built from a vagrant vm (virtualbox):

```
 https://github.com/razius/ppy-opencv-vagrant
```

I've installed libv4l-dev v4l-utils fswebcam gpicview libav-tools cheese, and I see the webcam listed in lsusb / usb-devices:

```
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 046d:092c Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Chat
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=046d ProdID=092c Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=
S:  Product=Camera
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
```

The same webcam on a debian vmware works fine, so how can I load the driver here?

Comment: What does `lsmod` say?

Comment: As @MatijaNalis implies, devices are handled by device drivers which become part of the kernel in the form of loadable modules, so we need to see if a suitable module has already been automatically loaded. If not, then we can figure out what module to load and load it temporarily (insmod) for testing and then add it permanently once it works.

Comment: @Ben Nguyen, do you solve the problem?